# Intermediate values through callback functions

Tags: optimization, callback, julia, julia-jump, ipopt

I am currently working on implementing an algorithm for solving a special type of optimization problem by using JuMP and IPOPT in Julia. This problem requires that I check some kind of statement for each iteration in IPOPT. If the statement comes true, `norm(currentValue,Inf) > η*max_val` I want IPOPT to terminate.

I have a vector containing many different expressions, for example like;

```
a = [x[1] + y^2, x[2] + 2y, x[3]^2]
```

I am using the callback function to get the different values of the variables at each iteration. However, for each iteration, I want to check the values inside `a`. I know that at the end (when optimize! has finished) I can check the values of the expressions by using `value.(a)`. Is it possible to do something similar inside the callback function? Something like this;

```
 function my_callback(
        alg_mod::Cint,
        iter_count::Cint,
        obj_value::Float64,
        inf_pr::Float64,
        inf_du::Float64,
        mu::Float64,
        d_norm::Float64,
        regularization_size::Float64,
        alpha_du::Float64,
        alpha_pr::Float64,
        ls_trials::Cint)

        x, z_L, z_U = zeros(n), zeros(n), zeros(n).     # x contains the values
        g, lambda = zeros(m), zeros(m)
        scaled = true
        prob = unsafe_backend(model).inner
        Ipopt.GetIpoptCurrentIterate(prob, scaled, n, x, z_L, z_U, m, g, lambda)
        x_L_violation, x_U_violation = zeros(n), zeros(n)
        compl_x_L, compl_x_U, grad_lag_x = zeros(n), zeros(n), zeros(n)
        nlp_constraint_violation, compl_g = zeros(m), zeros(m)
        Ipopt.GetIpoptCurrentViolations(
            prob,
            scaled,
            n,
            x_L_violation,
            x_U_violation,
            compl_x_L,
            compl_x_U,
            grad_lag_x,
            m,
            nlp_constraint_violation,
            compl_g,
        )
        currentValues = a(x) # this is what I want to do but is not working...
       
        return norm(currentValue,Inf) < η*max_val.  # the statement 
    end
    MOI.set(model, Ipopt.CallbackFunction(), my_callback)
    @test MOI.get(model, MOI.TerminationStatus()) == MOI.INTERRUPTED
```

So, my question is how to get the current value of an expression after each iteration in IPOPT using a callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the value of variables in a callback using `callback_value`. See the README for details: https://github.com/jump-dev/Ipopt.jl#solver-specific-callback.

Then, you can evaluate JuMP expressions using `value(f, expr)`, where `f(x)` returns the value of the variable `x`. For example:

```
julia> using JuMP, Ipopt, LinearAlgebra

julia> model = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)
A JuMP Model
Feasibility problem with:
Variables: 0
Model mode: AUTOMATIC
CachingOptimizer state: EMPTY_OPTIMIZER
Solver name: Ipopt

julia> @variable(model, x[1:3] >= 1)
3-element Vector{VariableRef}:
 x[1]
 x[2]
 x[3]

julia> @variable(model, y)
y

julia> a = [x[1] + y^2, x[2] + 2y, x[3]^2]
3-element Vector{QuadExpr}:
 y² + x[1]
 x[2] + 2 y
 x[3]²

julia> function my_callback(args...)
           function f(xi)
               return callback_value(model, xi)
           end
           a_value = value.(f, a)
           return LinearAlgebra.norm(a_value, Inf) < 0.1
       end
my_callback (generic function with 1 method)

julia> MOI.set(model, Ipopt.CallbackFunction(), my_callback)

julia> optimize!(model)
This is Ipopt version 3.14.4, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.4.1.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        0
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Total number of variables............................:        4
                     variables with only lower bounds:        3
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        0
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  0.0000000e+00 0.00e+00 1.00e+00  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0

Number of Iterations....: 0

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   1.0000000000000000e+00    1.0000000000000000e+00
Constraint violation....:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Variable bound violation:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   9.9999999999998979e-03    9.9999999999998979e-03
Overall NLP error.......:   1.0000000000000000e+00    1.0000000000000000e+00


Number of objective function evaluations             = 1
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 1
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 0
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 0
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 0
Total seconds in IPOPT                               = 0.116

EXIT: Stopping optimization at current point as requested by user.

julia> @test MOI.get(model, MOI.TerminationStatus()) == MOI.INTERRUPTED 
Test Passed
```

p.s., consider posting these sorts of questions on the Discourse forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13.